# Angular: How to get image width and height before putting it on the DOM

Tags: angular, image, typescript

I'm pretty new to Angular & Typescript and this may sounds a silly question.

I have an Array of image urls/meta-data loaded from a local .json by a service.
In the single-image view component I have:

```
...
<img [src]="my_picture.large" [alt]="my_picture.title">
...
```

I would like to get more information of my_picture.large BEFORE loading it into the DOM. Is it possible?
For example, I'd like to know its width and height, its aspect ratio, and react with a different template if portrait or landscape.

Of course I could add a meta information on the json file, but as I stated before I'm learning and I'm trying to figure out the best angular way to solve problems. :)

A related question: Can I pre-load images before putting them on the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    const determineDimensions = (ImageUrl) => {   
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        console.log(this.width, this.height);
    };
    img.src = ImageUrl;
    }
```

Comment: Oh thank you, I wrote a function with Image object and it works!

Your example gave me this error:
`error TS2339: Property 'width' does not exist on type 'GlobalEventHandlers'.`